# Why these two dates are not equal in javascript?

Tags: javascript, equality

I'm comparing two dates in objA and objB, and they are not equal as the following console output shows.
Can't understand why..

```
objA[keysA[i]]
Sun Sep 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (KST)
objB[keysA[i]]
Sun Sep 25 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (KST)
typeof objA[keysA[i]]
"object"
typeof objB[keysA[i]]
"object"
objA[keysA[i]] !== objB[keysA[i]]
true
```

Comment: because dates are an object you can not compare them like that ... try `objA[keysA[i]]+0 !== objB[keysA[i]]+0` which coerces the dates to a Number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you compare objects by reference.

```
let a = {};
let b = {};
let c = a;

a == b //false
a == c //true
```

A simple way of comparing objects is to convert them to a string and compare the string. You can use `Date.prototype.toString` to compare `Date` objects like this

```
objA[keysA[i]].toString() !== objB[keysA[i]]].toString() //false
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to stringify the dates & compare them that way. For example:

```
var date1 = new Date(); 
var date2 = new Date();

console.log (date1==date2); // This will print false
```

But if we stringify the dates and compare them that way this will become true, like so:

```
console.log (date1.toString() === date2.toString())
```

Comment: date1+0 === date2+0 as well - and accounts for millisecond differences

Comment: Yep. @JaromandaX - If you were to do `date1+0 === date2+0` | It'd = true as you said.